# How to analyze 'last night' and 'last/next week'?

Tags: adverbs, pronouns, determiners

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Page 429) says:

> *Yesterday*, *today*, *tonight*, and *tomorrow* are not traditionally analysed as pronouns, but belong in this subclass of nouns by virtue of their inability to take determiners. Compare, for example, *Today*/**The today is my birthday*. They are also semantically like the central pronouns ***I*** and ***you*** in that they are characteristically used deictically. Unlike the temporal prepositions *now* and *then*, the pronouns have genitive forms: *today’s*, etc.

Expressions like *last night* and *last/next week* act just like *yesterday*, *today*, *tonight*, and *tomorrow*: They cannot take determiners without changing the meaning; they are characteristically used deictically; and they have genitive forms (*last night's*, etc.)

Although *last night* and *last/next week* are made up of two words, some pronouns such as reciprocal pronouns (*each other*, *one another*) are also two-word expressions, so being made up of two words shouldn't stop them from being pronouns.

In the determinative section, though, CGEL also mentions in a foodnote (Page 356):

> We might also include [in the determinative category] *last* and *next* as used in temporal deictic expressions such as *last week*, *next year*, etc., where they contrast with the central determinative *this*.

But it's not clear how CGEL would analyze *last night* and *last/next week*.

**Question 1**

Would CGEL analyze *last night* and *last/next week* as pronouns or a combination of 'determiner (*last*, *next*, etc) + common noun (*night*, *week*, etc)'?

**Question 2**

If CGEL adopts the 'determiner + common noun' approach for *last night* and *last/next week*, why doesn't CGEL adopt the 'determiner + common noun' approach for *yesterday*, *today*, *tonight*, and *tomorrow* (with  *yester-/to-* being a determiner and *-day/night/morrow* being a common noun)?

Comment: Haven't you answered your own question 1 with the footnote quote? *Last* in *last week* is a determinative. That would make *week* a noun. As for question 2, I'm not sure why you're deconstructing words; *yester* does not stand alone (not anymore anyway).

Comment: @TinfoilHat In the footnote, they say "We might also include..." but the fact of the matter is, they didn't. So isn't it correct to say that they decided not to include _last_ and _next_ in the determinative category? //I'm not trying to deconstruct words, I'm trying to understand why those four words can **function** as pronouns, adjectives, and adverbs by looking at their etymology.

Comment: See CGEL p. 564 regarding comparison to traditional grammar: *There is, however, no need to distinguish the **yesterday** of [i] and [ii] in terms of category as well as function . . .* Also, that "might" sounds kind of British English to me — as in *might well*, not as in *might but not yet*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Good point. So the function of the four words is pronoun. // Whether the _might_ means "might well" or "might but not yet", it's a fact that CGEL didn't officially include _last_ and _next_ as the determinative, isn't it?

Comment: Or is it that they are categorically pronouns, but we don't say what they function as? I would say a British *we might* in this case might be a sort of polite *we do*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat What I'm saying is the fact that CGEL doesn't list _last_ and _next_ under **§7 Other determinatives** (p 373). "In this section we examine in turn the groups of determinatives given in [5] of §4 other than the two articles. Our major focus will be on their use in determiner function, with other uses being dealt with more summarily."

Comment: Maybe more clues at *Chapter 8: § 6.2 Semantic types* and *Chapter 17: § 10.1.2 Other temporal expressions*.

Comment: Once again, why ask us what they would say when you can send them an email and get the actual facts?

Comment: @JohnLawler There's [an argument going on about depictive adjectives](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/534942/why-is-it-i-did-that-wrong-instead-of-i-did-that-wrongly/534943#comment1308284_534943)which I think would benefit greatly from your involvement.

Comment: @TinfoilHat Those sections do discuss the expressions but they don't analyze _last_ or _next_.