# Why is it "I did that wrong" instead of "I did that wrongly"?

Tags: grammar

It seems that "in a manner such that it is wrong" should be "wrongly", not just "wrong"...

Comment: It's not. Please don't post mistakes or (as here) colloquial / dialect variants without linked, attributed references. 'Wrong' here is an example of a _flat adverb_ usage, best avoided in academic writing.

Comment: I am sorry, I have no idea how to post linked attributed references, or what those are.

Comment: Greybeard says that it is not an adverb...

Comment: I've asked him to delete that misleading answer. 'I did that wrong' where 'I did that wrongly' would work (contrast 'She done him wrong') certainly uses 'wrong' as a (flat) adverb. How acceptable this is is something usage groups disagree on; certainly, it is best avoided in formal registers.

Comment: Oh, why didn't you tell me that before! So, something to avoid in formal registers. And what would be the formal phrasing, then?

Comment: 'I did that wrongly' means 'my methodology was incorrect'. And you do emphasise the _manner_ of doing.  If you meant 'I got it wrong', referring to the result rather than the way you tackled the situation, your question here needs correcting. Referring to the result, 'I got it wrong' is acceptable in all but the most formal contexts (in the UK, perhaps in all contexts in the US). 'I was wrong' works in any register.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth (and whoever else has vote-to-close superpowers): I'd like to see this question reopened, as the quick/quickly answer does not fully apply to the wrong/wrongly adverbs (which are not always interchangeable). See [Wrong and wrongly](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-wro2.htm).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks! I didn't think of the distinction between result and process when asking the question. But  "I was wrong" works only for immaterial things, like opinions, not for material results. So what would be a formal phrasing for material results?

Comment: Ah, [the Green Conspiracy](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/111065/15299). See Georgia Green, 1970. "How abstract is surface structure?" CLS 6, 270–281.

Answer (score -1):

> Why is it “I did that wrong” instead of “I did that wrongly”?

Compare

"She arrived at the meeting **drunk** (adjective)." = "She arrived at the meeting [and she was] drunk." The adjective "drunk" is known as a depictive.

with

"She arrived at the meeting **drunkenly** (adverb)." = "She arrived at the meeting as if she were drunk." - she need not be drunk... perhaps she was ill or dizzy.

and

"He hammered the metal **flat** (adjective)." = "He hammered the metal [and as a result, it was] flat." - The adjective "flat" is known as a resultative.

With

"He hammered the metal **flatly**." (adjective) = "He hammered the metal in a plain, blunt, or decisive manner."[1]

The adjective is used as a free modifier/complement. "Wrong" is **not** an adverb, "wrongly" is.

Note:
I shot him **dead**.

But

*I shot him **deadly**.

Thus

“I did that wrong” - I did that and it was wrong.

For further reading, "Resultatives Under the ‘Event-Argument Homomorphism’ Model of Telicity" by Stephen Wechsler, University of Texas at Austin is very accessible.

[1]definition from OED.

Comment: Whilst I agree with all you say about depictives - and "she arrived drunk" is clearly a good example. And while "wrong" can be so used - "It is wrong to kill a fly* - I am not sure that "I did that wrong" is a depictive. Depictively wouldn't it be "I got that wrong". Though I accept that the verb "do" can take a depictive - as in "I did the eggs soft*. What do you think? Could I say "I did the eggs wrong"?  Whichever way I upvote your good answer.

Comment: Please delete this answer. The question is (a) about 'wrong' used as a flat adverb form of wrongly, not as a depictive adjective (cf the arguably resultative, and certainly adjectival,  example 'I marked question 7 wrong'. And (b) a multi-duplicate. eg '... pedantic prescriptivism. Some adverbs don’t change from their adjectival forms. These are known as flat adverbs. A few of the most common ones are close, deep, fast, quick, and right. Some of these have corresponding -ly adverbs with which they are interchangeable—for example, come quick and come quickly mean the same thing.– FumbleFingers'

Comment: @WS2 - I take your point and I think that the example is just within the margin to be accepted as adjectival. ++ **Wrong** and **did** are, as you point out somewhat vague - if we were to say "I cooked the eggs (i) mistakenly/ (ii) mistaken." we can see a difference that can transfer to "wrong" and "did". - "mistakenly" qualifies "cooked" but "mistaken" describes your state.whilst cooking - the result might or might not be the same.either way, "I did the eggs wrong." seems to be acceptable, but in formal style I would rephrase.

Comment: Please don't delete this discussion. It's enlightening for those of us who are learning.

Comment: @Philosopherofscience: The problem is that the answer is wrong. In *I did that wrong*, *wrong* is an adverb—and a perfectly acceptable one here. You can swap in a different adverb to see: *I did that incorrectly.* See [Wrong and wrongly](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-wro2.htm)

Comment: @TinfoilHat Couldn't agree more. _Greybeard answered the question wrong_ sounds more natural to my ear than _Greybeard answered the question wrongly_. The latter sounds somewhat stilted albeit grammatical. And the former doesn't mean the question is wrong; it means the answer is wrong.